# modify the dmi/bios values for a hyper-v vm

Tags: hyper-v

I'd like to be able to modify the values Hyper-V returns when you query the dmi/bios (the values are being viewed with dmidecode on the guest os).

I can see Hyper-V queries reg key "AC6B8DC1-3257-4A70-B1B2-A9C9215659AD", which points to the c:\Windows\System32\vmchipset.dll, which looks promising.

I also see the new vmcx file has a section '*ac6b8dc1-3257-4a70-b1b2-a9c9215659ad*, which again looks promising.

However, I can't see anyway to to edit the values returned by dmi.

Answer (score 0):

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c9e3db9a-1aed-4b14-b62d-a1c4c7419fad/hyperv-wmi-how-to-pass-a-parameter-as-a-string?forum=netfxbcl seems to contain one of the only answers, which references http://www.hurryupandwait.io/blog/a-packer-template-for-windows-nano-server-weighing-300mb

I am not sure if a non-Creative Commons code example can be reproduced here but https://powershellmagazine.com/2014/04/16/pstip-pause-after-uefi-boot-failure-when-using-hyper-v-generation-2-virtual-machines/ also shows that attributes like BIOSGUID, ChassisAssetTag and ChassisSerialNumber can be modified via CIM.